# Rango de horas de inicio y final php mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

resulta que tengo 3 salas, estoy haciendo un calendario para poder agendar horarios que se puede usar cada sala, el problema es la validación.
Por ejemplo si agendaron la sala de 14 a 16 no se puede usar esa misma sala en ese horario, tendría que usar otra, he podido validar la hora de entrada con el siguiente código:

```
$q = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE sala = '$sala' AND inicio_normal = '$inicio_normal'");
```

Pero resulta que si una persona reserva la sala de 15 a 16 el sistema le permite y no debería, porque ya esta ocupada de 14 a 16.

El campo de la tabla hora de entrada y hora de salida es un VARCHAR, toma el valor del campo input date, estoy usando un datetimepicker.

Estoy usando Php 7

Alguien que me pueda ayudar.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si pones la estructura de la tabla sería mas fácil. Pregunta: `inicio_normal` cómo está definida en la tabla y cómo es el dato `$inicio_normal`? Es un objeto datetime? Qué DBMS y versión de PHP estás usando?

Comment: Ahi edite la pregunta. Gracias

Comment: Deberías leer sobre los campos date en [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) y en [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

Comment: No he podido solucionar todavia, si cambio el campo a DATATIME no ingresa nada en el campo, ¿hay alguna forma de hacerlo sin cambiar el campo a DATATIME?

Answer (score 0):

La columna `inicio_normal` debe ser de tipo [DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) y, suponiendo que tienes otra columna `fin_normal` del mismo tipo para delimitar el tiempo de uso, reemplaza `hora-inicio` y `hora-fin` con los valores obtenidos por formulario en los siguientes ejemplos:

```
SELECT *
FROM agenda
WHERE sala = '$sala'
    AND (inicio_normal >= 'hora-inicio' AND fin_normal <= 'hora-inicio')
```

Si la consulta anterior devuelve resultados, quiere decir que la sala ya está reservada durante la hora de inicio seleccionada.

```
SELECT *
FROM agenda
WHERE sala = '$sala'
    AND (inicio_normal >= 'hora-fin' AND fin_normal <= 'hora-fin')
```

Si esta otra devuelve resultados, la sala está reservada durante la hora de fin seleccionada.

Creo que lo adecuado sería ejecutar esas dos consultas por separado para que puedas proporcionar el mensaje de error que corresponda, porque si lo haces solo con una consulta, sería más difícil determinar dónde está el error, si en el horario de inicio o final:

```
SELECT *
FROM agenda
WHERE sala = '$sala' AND (
    (inicio_normal >= 'hora-inicio' AND fin_normal <= 'hora-inicio')
    OR (inicio_normal >= 'hora-fin' AND fin_normal <= 'hora-fin')
)
```

También hay otras opciones, como realizar subconsultas para buscar ambos resultados al mismo tiempo y obtenerlos como columnas, pero eso ya escapa del tema.

Siempre es buena idea probar las consultas en PhpMyAdmin (o el gestor de base de datos de tu preferencia) antes de agregarlas al código.

**Importante:** Tus consultas son susceptibles a ataques SQL, te recomiendo migrar a [consultas preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).